# Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/ • should NOT have additional property 'config'

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, config

I'm using ReactNative Expo for developing android/iOS app also added AdMOB. Issue is when I run expo build:ios, it's returning following error Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/  • should NOT have additional property 'config'.

Here is my app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "slug": "AppSlug",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.x.yyyyy",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a silly typing mistake. You have to put "config" key inside "ios".

This will fix your problem:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "slug": "AppSlug",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.x.yyyyy",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's just a silly typo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't us any space or underscore in slug.